# Download invoice PDF file through the Priority Web SDK

Tags: priority-web-sdk

Is there an option to download the invoice PDF file through the Priority Web SDK?

I see in documentation only options to upload files https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/#uploadFile

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the pdf through WebSDK:
You need to invoke a procedure that does it.
See [Documentation](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/procedure/#Introduction) for explanation.